# jupyter notebook %debug magic fails to show prompt

Tags: python, debugging, jupyter-notebook

Sometimes when I use `%debug` in jupyter notebook, it shows only the traceback, but does not display the prompt. Hence, I cannot debug, and have to restart the kernel to re-run the Python code that encounters an exception. Even after restarting the kernel, `%debug` may still fail to show the REPL prompt. The issue never occurs after first starting a new notebook server, and running `%debug` for the first time on this new server. It does seem more prone to happen if I forget to type `exit` at the prompt before restarting the kernel, but can still occur if I remember to do so.

I started the notebook server for debugging purposes as follows:
`jupyter notebook --debug > log.file 2>&1`

The resulting log didn't show anything of concern. It is difficult to isolate the error case to a single example.

The only elements that caught my eye in the console are

```
404 Extension failed to load http://localhost:8888/nbextensions/widgets/notebook/js/extension.js?v=20170321160448
```

and

```
Widgets are not available.  Please install widgetsnbextension or ipywidgets 4.0
```

My `~/.jupyter/custom/custom.js` is completely commented out.

I have recently run both (and issue still occurs after restarting the server):

```
pip install --upgrade https://github.com/ipython-contrib/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions/tarball/master
```

and

```
pip install --upgrade widgetsnbextension
```

What could be causing this problem? How could I fix it?

Comment: Have you done pip install -U ipywidgets?

Comment: @mprat it appears that `ipywidgets` was 5.2.2 on my global python install, and not installed in the `virtualenv` environment I'm using. Running that command on global upgraded to 6.0.0, and installed 6.0.0 for the first time in the virtualenv. However, the REPL not appearing issue also exists while running with my global python install (i.e. with ipywidgets 5.2.2, but without the console exception). I haven't tested with 6.0.0 yet, but will inform if it fixes